# Access application-saved data from a web browser

Tags: selenium, cookies, desktop-application

We have a desktop application for which the user enters some registration details (e.g. support code), and can then use the application.

We would like to be able to automatically fill our support website ticket form with this information, even if the desktop application is not running.

So far we've considered:

- [InternetSetCookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetcookiea) - but it only works for Windows+IE
- use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to create cookies for all major browsers (seems an overkill, and required us to distribute Selenium along with our app)
- have a JS service always run in the background

Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Did you consider client certificates for authentication? You could fetch a client certificate with your application and install it to the local Windows account.

Comment: @Jens sounds interesting. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I am not an expert and I would ask at Super User or Server Fault. You could start at https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326 to get the basics, but I do not know how to import the certificate in a local browser installation by your own software.